# How to raise an error odoo while selecting multiple items in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

How can I raise an error while the user selects multiple items from many2many fields? The user can select only one item if he selects multiple items then I want to raise an error.

```
user_ids = fields.Many2many('res.users', string="Salesperson", required=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to detect server sidely how many records are selected in your `Many2many` field, this requires a client-side approach (injecting some javascripts)

However, you could validate your field content length before saving parent record.

```
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

user_ids = fields.Many2many('res.users', string="Salesperson", required=False)

def write(self, values):
  res = super(MyModel, self).write(values)

  for record in self:
    if len(record.user_ids) > 1:
      raise ValidationError("No multiple items allowed")
  
  return res
```

If you always intend to have only a single relation, consider using `Many2one` instead.

`user_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.users', string="Salesperson", required=False)`